# Adding friends from address book using Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, addressbook, relation

I'm building an app and at sign up/log in, it will go through the users address book, take the phone numbers, check against phone number column in the User class on Parse and if they aren't friends, then add them.

I have a function in AddressBookHelper.swift to help get the phone numbers:

```
class AddressBookHelper: NSObject {

let addressBook = AFAddressBookManager()

static var addressBookData = AFAddressBookManager.allContactsFromAddressBook()
static var contactsArray = [String]()

static func getContacts() -> [String] {

    var array = [String]()
    for contact in addressBookData{
        let phoneNumberArray = contact.numbers as! [String]
        for number in phoneNumberArray{ 
            array.append(number)  
        }
    }

    return array

}

}
```

Then in ParseHelper.swift I do the check again Parse User class:

```
static func lookUpUserFromAddressBook(addressBook: [String], completionBlock: PFArrayResultBlock) {

    for numbers in addressBook{
        let query = User.query()
        query!.whereKey("telephone", equalTo:numbers)
        query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(completionBlock)
    }

}
```

And lastly, when the button is clicked, I add the user as a friend, if not already a friend:

```
@IBAction func importContacts(sender: AnyObject) {

    ParseHelper.lookUpUserFromAddressBook(AddressBookHelper.getContacts())  {
        (results: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            if let objects = results as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {

                    let userObject = object as! User
                    self.matchedUsers.append(userObject)

                    let query = PFQuery(className: "Friends")
                    query.includeKey("toUser")
                    query.whereKey("fromUser", equalTo: User.currentUser()!)
                    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                        if error == nil {
                            if (objects!.count == 0) {

                                ParseHelper.addFollowRelationshipFromUser(fromUser: User.currentUser()!, toUser: userObject, completionBlock: { (success, error) -> Void in


                                    if success{
                                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("skipped", sender: self)
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")

                                    }
                                })
                            }
                            else{
                                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("skipped", sender: self)
                            }

                        } else {
                            print("Error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo)")
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }

    }

}
```

Am I doing this the right way? It works, but the code seems a bit long. Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at PFQuery's `whereKey:containedIn:`. This will return you a list of all users whose phone numbers match any of the numbers you pass in an array. This will greatly reduce the number of queries you need to do to retrieve the user's contacts.

```
// Find users with any of these phone numbers
let numbers = ["1234567890", "1111111111", "222222222"]
query.whereKey("phoneNumber", containedIn: numbers)
```

From the Parse iOS Developers Guide:
https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries

> If you want to retrieve objects matching several different values, you
>   can use whereKey:containedIn:, providing an array of acceptable
>   values. This is often useful to replace multiple queries with a single
>   query.

You can also create all the follow relationships in one query using PFObject.saveAllInBackground() which takes an array of PFObjects to save.

Comment: Would changing to this help?

static func lookUpUserFromAddressBook(addressBook: [String], completionBlock: PFArrayResultBlock) {
        let query = User.query()
        query!.whereKey("telephone", containedIn: addressBook)
        query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(completionBlock)
    }

Comment: Yes, that's one thing that would help.